# AWS .NET SDK on Linux

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I am currently moving an ASP.NET application made by a third party from Windows to Linux. I read the documentation and nothing indicates this should be a problem, but sadly

```
var profile = new CredentialProfile(profileName, credentials) {
    Region = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1
};

var netSDKFile = new NetSDKCredentialsFile();
netSDKFile.RegisterProfile(profile);
```

throws the following exception

```
Unhandled Exception: Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: The encrypted store is not available.  This may be due to use of a non-Windows operating system or Windows Nano Server, or the current user account may not have its profile loaded.
   at Amazon.Util.Internal.SettingsManager.EnsureAvailable()
   at Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.NetSDKCredentialsFile..ctor()
```

Is the Amazon .NET SDK(or a part of it) not supported on Linux? If that is the case, is there a possible workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part there is very little that isn't supported on Linux that is supported on Windows. Off of the top of my head I can't think of anything besides `NetSDKCredentialsFile` which is due to the fact it uses Win32 API to encrypt credentials.

You can use `SharedCredentialsFile` to register a profile in the credentials file stored under `~/.aws/credentials`. This is the same credential stored supported by all of the other AWS SDK and Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Norm's answer, I found this resource that explained how to use Shared Credentials: https://medium.com/@somchat/programming-using-aws-net-sdk-9ce3f5119633

This is how I was previously using NetSDKCredentials, which won't work for Linux/Mac OS:

```
//Try this code on a non-Windows platform and you will see the above error
var options = new CredentialProfileOptions
  {
    AccessKey = "access_key",
    SecretKey = "secret_key"
  };
var profile = new CredentialProfile("default", options);
profile.Region = RegionEndpoint.USWest1;
NetSDKCredentialsFile file = new NetSDKCredentialsFile();
file.RegisterProfile(profile);
```

But I was then able to use this example to use SharedCredentials:

```
var credProfileStoreChain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
if (credProfileStoreChain.TryGetAWSCredentials("default", out AWSCredentials awsCredentials))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Access Key: " + awsCredentials.GetCredentials().AccessKey);
  Console.WriteLine("Secret Key: " + awsCredentials.GetCredentials().SecretKey);
}
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

You'll then be able to see your code is able to access the keys:

```
Access Key: A..................Q
Secret Key: 8.......................................p
Hello World!
```

I then used System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform() (as I am using this code on both Windows and Linux), to determine which credentials to use:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//NETSDK Credentials only work on Windows - must use SharedCredentials on Linux
bool isLinux = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux);

if (isLinux) {

    //Use SharedCredentials
            
} else { 

    //Use NetSDKCredentials

}
```

You may find this section of the AWS documentation helpful, too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#creds-locate