# AWS .NET - Difference between SharedCredentialsFile and NetSDKCredentialsFile

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-toolkit

I was following the [AWS tutorials for .NET developers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) and found out that it features the usage of both `SharedCredentialsFile` and `NetSDKCredentialsFile`. Is there any difference between those two APIs? In my code, they can be interchanged without any apparent difference:

```
    public CredentialProfile GetProfile(string profileName)
    {
        // Which one should I use?
        var sharedFile = new SharedCredentialsFile();
        //var sharedFile = new NetSDKCredentialsFile();

        if (!sharedFile.TryGetProfile(profileName, out var result))
        {
            var options = new CredentialProfileOptions
            {
                AccessKey = Configuration.AccessKey,
                SecretKey = Configuration.SecretKey
            };

            var profile = new CredentialProfile(profileName, options);
            profile.Region = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;
            sharedFile .RegisterProfile(profile);

            result = profile;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Is one of them obsolete? Is there a best practice to which one should be used? Or are they identical?

Note, that I am developing on a Windows PC, but the app will run on a Linux server. Could this make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio integrates with both NetSDKCredentialsFile and SharedCredentialsFile. NetSDKCredentialsFile was the original credential store for the .NET SDK before AWS SDKs unified around the .aws/credentials file which SharedCredentialsFile manages. At this point I would recommend using SharedCredentialsFile so your credentials will be compatible with all of the other AWS tools and SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer here: [AWS .NET SDK on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474210/aws-net-sdk-on-linux)

- `NetSDKCredentialsFile` makes use of the same store as AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio, but it does not work on Linux.
- `SharedCredentialsFile` is not integrated with the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio, but works on all platforms.

Comment: Actually the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio integrates with both NetSDKCredentialsFile and SharedCredentialsFile. NetSDKCredentialsFile was the original credential store for the .NET SDK before AWS SDKs unified around the .aws/credentials file which SharedCredentialsFile manages. At this point I would recommend using SharedCredentialsFile so your credentials will be compatible with all of the other AWS tools and SDKs.

Comment: @NormJohanson, could you post this as a standalone answer? I think it contains more details than my answer and it might be more useful to other developers.